# Update the Azure App registration web.logoutUrl using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am using an Azure CLI script to register an application like this:

```
az ad app create --display-name $appName
    --sign-in-audience AzureADMyOrg
    --enable-id-token-issuance true
    --enable-access-token-issuance false
    --required-resource-accesses @app-resources.json
    --web-redirect-uris $redirectUris
```

I need to set the front-channel logout URL as well, but I don't see a way to include that in the app create command.

I've also tried using update commands like these to set it after the application is created:

```
az ad app update --id {id} --set logoutUrl="https://someurl"
az ad app update --id {id} --set web.logoutUrl="https://someurl"
az ad app update --id {id} --set web[logoutUrl]="https://someurl"
az ad app update --id {id} --set web=@{ logoutUrl = "https://someurl" }
```

but I can't figure out the correct syntax. They all return errors along the lines of

```
Couldn't find 'web' in 'web'. Available options: []
```

How do I set the logoutUrl for an application using Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2):

As per [this reply](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10579#issuecomment-601643464) another relatively low-friction workaround for this option not being (currently) supported by the az cli command itself, is to use the graph api (via the az rest command) to set the logout url.

Below snippet gets the default hostname of an Azure Static Web App and updates the related app registration accordingly:

```
$swa = az staticwebapp show -n "SWA_NAME_HERE" -g "RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME_HERE" | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 10 
$swaHostUrl = "https://{0}" -f $swa.defaultHostname 
$AppId = "GUID_HERE"
az ad app update --id $AppId --web-redirect-uris "$swaHostUrl/.auth/login/aad/callback" --enable-id-token-issuance true
# Need to workaround via MSGraph to set the logout url... sigh...
$appReg = az ad app show --id $AppId | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 10
$body = @{ web = @{ logoutUrl = ("{0}/.auth/logout/aad/callback" -f $swaHostUrl) } } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
# We need the object id for this bit
az rest --method PATCH --uri ('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{0}' -f $appReg.id) --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body ($body -replace '"', '\"')
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tried adding logoutUrl for the service principal/app registration using either of these `set-azureserviceprincipal`, `update-azadserviceprincipal`, `az ad app update` cmdlets unfortunately it is not working and facing the same error.

Alternatively, i would suggest you to edit the  **logoutUrl** value through manifest file in portal.
Here are the steps:

1. login to the azure portal.
2. Search for Active directory --> select app registrations and particular app registration name.
3. go to the Manifest option under manage as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am able to set it through the portal through either the Authentication section or the manifest. My goal is to be able to script the entire creation process since we often need to create them for multiple environments. The script would make it faster and be sure they are created in a consistent way.